# Overlaying image onto a HTML table

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to web design so yeah, but basically I have a table, two rows, I have an image that I want to be over the top of the right hand side of the table as a semi-transparent overlay, I also have bootstrap controlling other elements on this webpage so I'm not sure if that's preventing the styles from being applied but anyway this is my code, any pointers please?!

The table will eventually display data in a list which will make up a 'leaders chart', hence why I've named the class 'chart'.

```
<div class="chart">
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>26</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>30</td>
 <img src="images/triangle.png" alt="triangle"/>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart {position: relative;}
.img
{position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 opacity: 0.9;}
```

When inspecting in the browser, it appears that none of the CSS is being applied to the .chart or the .img, the chart has no css applied to it and the .img only appears to have a border set by default bootstrap css file.

any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I posted a possible answer check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `.img` in your CSS, but there is no element with `class="img"` in your markup. I'm assuming you are trying to target the `img` in your code, so you would either add `class="img"` to your `img` tag, or change your CSS selector to target the element `img` instead of the class `.img`.

The `.chart` CSS seems fine, but you won't see any visual indication of the style changes you made to it, since it's just `position: relative`. You should see that style applied to `.chart` if you look at the styles for that element in the dev console.

```css
.chart {
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="chart">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <img class="img" src="images/triangle.png" alt="triangle" />
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. You can't place the img where you have currently. Looking at your
   css I think I can see what you are trying to achieve. Try placing it
   after the tables closing `</table>` tag and before the `.chart`
   closing `</div>` tag.
2. add `class="img"` to your `img` element.
       Your css has used a class selector for your `img`. Otherwise change
       your css to `img` instead of `.img`.

Your implementation of `.chart {position: relative;}` looks fine. That should definitely be working and should appear when you inspect the `.chart` div in the inspector.

Comment: Thanks very much will give this a go!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `.chart` CSS will not show any visual effect, since it is just `position: relative`. But, if you want to see the style reference for that element then use the developer console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome or Firefox on Windows or Linux environments.
2. Also, I found that you are using `.img` in your CSS, but there are no elements with `class="img"` in your HTML code. So, if you are trying to target the `img` tag then you should change your CSS selector to target the element `img` using a parent class like this `.chart > img`.

Now, here you have the modified code:

```css
.chart {
  position: relative;
}

.chart img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="chart">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/2RlpzDi.png?1" alt="triangle" />
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you think this is the solution please mark it as answered to help other to identify solved questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all replies, they helped alot, even when I implemented this corrected code, I could still not get my image to sit over the top of the table, after much troubleshooting in the CSS file I have fixed the issue, it turns out the that the problem was that this CSS:

```
.chart {
position: relative;
}

.img {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
opacity: 0.9;
}
```

was AFTER this @media line:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px){
```

I have now put the CSS for .chart & .img before it and works perfectly, thankyou.